# Is Terrain and Topographic Correction the same for Landsat8?

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat

Landsat 8 L1 products are "Terrain Corrected",

that said it means that are they already "topographically corrected", like both words are synonyms or you need to apply correction techniques as well? (eg [i.topo.corr](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/i.topo.corr.html) for Grass)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to section [10.2 Level 1 Algorithms](http://landsathandbook.gsfc.nasa.gov/level/prog_sect10_2.html) from NASA's [Landsat 7 Science Data Users Handbook](http://landsathandbook.gsfc.nasa.gov/pdfs/Landsat7_Handbook.pdf), all Landsat 7 Level **1T** products are corrected for terrain effects (see also [*Figure 10.4*](http://landsathandbook.gsfc.nasa.gov/level/prog_sect10_2.html#fig10_4)). The same applies for Landsat 8 data of level *1T* which refers to *Standard Terrain Correction (Level 1T)*.

The correction(s) might not be perfect.  Thus, one can, in theory, undergo a more detailed process for ortho-rectifying Landsat L1G products by using a DEM of higher resolution/quality than the well known DEMs [SRTM](http://www2.jpl.nasa.gov/srtm/) or/and [ASTER GDEM](http://www.jspacesystems.or.jp/ersdac/GDEM/E/)(2) both of which can be considered, depending on the application, as being *coarse*.

Comment: Then can I conclude If I use 1T data then no need of topographic/illumination correction using coarser DEM like ASTER, SRTM etc?

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but I think a clarification might be useful generally.

- The term *topographic correction* should mean correcting for *slope
  illumination*. For example for
  the purpose of cover type classification it is desirable, that the
  image color is function of the cover type and not the illumination
  angle etc., but slope side towards the sun is lighter and the other is
  darker. Topographic correction tries to remove this effect - as does
  the i.topo.corr GRASS GIS command. This type of correction is usually
  not part of level-1 processing, but may (or may not) be part of
  level-2 processing chain (atmospherically corrected products).
- Term *terrain correction* is usually connected with *geometric effects* of
  terrain, i.e. correcting shift of surface feature pixel positions in
  image due to terrain elevation and observation angles from the
  satellite. The terms are often mixed, but in the description of
  Level-1T products, it has this geometric meaning. See descriptions in
  Table 2-1 on page 3 in section 2 of document
  https://landsat.usgs.gov/sites/default/files/documents/LSDS-1656_Landsat_Level-1_Product_Collection_Definition.pdf